# .hide() is not working in Firefox but working in IE

Tags: jquery

I want to display a layer and after clicking the close button I need to hide a layer.

for this I am passing the value to the close function (user defined) in the jquery and used the below lines to close. Well it is working in IE but not working in Firefox.

```
$('.layer_close').click(function(){
    $('#TB_overlay').hide();
```

I tried to add the below code also but not helpful

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery.noConflict(); 

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    //Do jQuery stuff using $ 
        ... 
        ... 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML code, I'd suggest that you verify that TB_overlay is assigned an ID attribute, and not just a NAME.    I want to recall that IE will sometimes assume such things when absent...

Comment: This would be my guess as well. Although i assume by the ID hes doing some custom work to Thickbox, so all the id's should be correct as far as the overlay goes.